# Is it possible to transfer the input processing data to another CPU on another device?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

My goal is to transfer the input processing data to another CPU on another device.
For example, from one OS to another OS.
[image]

Comment: Please do not use external images. This question is way to unclear. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow.. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  You are doing it when you interact with SO servers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this kind of job transfer in done in many different scenario:   Oracle Parallel Server (https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/oracle8/server.815/a67439/chap1.htm):

[image]

The technical term where you can find answer are "process migration" and "distributed system management".  (https://www.slideshare.net/ayyakathir/cs6601-distributed-systems-70362190)

[image]

**Opensource example of this are Hadoop - shown here are batch process migration in Hadoop:**

[image]